# TypeError: io.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, multiplayer

I am following a tutorial for a simple multiplayer game using node js and socket.io (http://rawkes.com/articles/creating-a-real-time-multiplayer-game-with-websockets-and-node.html) . I am having a problem when i am trying to connect to the socket server.I get an error saying 
TypeError: io.connect is not a function
PS : i am a total beginner in node js and socket.io so please help me out.

```
var util = require("util");
io = require("socket.io"),
    Player = require("./Player").Player;
var socket, players;
function init(){
    players = [];

    socket = io.listen(8000);

    socket.configure(function() {
        socket.set("transports", ["websocket"]);
        socket.set("log level", 2);
    });

    setEventHandlers();

    socket = io.connect("http://localhost", {port: 8000, transports: ["websocket"]});

};
```

Comment: did you called `init` function in your js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** `socket = io.connect("http://localhost", {port: 8000, transports: ["websocket"]});` this has to be included in the client side javascript file where you load `socket.io.js` via script tag.

**Change to this:**

```
var util = require("util"),
    io = require("socket.io")({
      transports  : [ 'websocket' ]
    }),
    Player = require("./Player").Player,
    socket,
    players;

function init(){
    players = [];

    socket = io.listen(8000);

    setEventHandlers();

};
init();
```

**Note** Below is not supported by socket.io v1.0 you have to install v0.9 if you want to do it that way, use: `$ npm install socket.io@0.9 -S`

```
socket.configure(function() {
    socket.set("transports", ["websocket"]);
    socket.set("log level", 2);
});
```

**Looging** socket.io v1.0 `log-level` option is removed. Thus for logging one has to start program using debug module.

1. install debug: `npm install debug -S`
2. then run the program: `DEBUG=* node entry_file.js`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!